# How to make sure a type parameter is used only covariantly?

Tags: java, unit-testing, generics, static-analysis, covariance

Suppose I have a generic interface `Source<T>` which is a pure producer of `T` objects. Being a pure producer is part of the contract of the interface. So [it is a reasonable expectation](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/generics.pdf) that whatever you can do with a `Source<Foo>`, should be also possible to do if you have a `Source<? extends Foo>`.

Now I need to enforce this restriction in the body of `Source`, so that someone does not accidentally use `T` in a way that contradicts that contract.

**An example from the JDK**

As @Miserable.Variable points out, `ArrayList<Integer>` and `ArrayList<? extends Integer>` are *not* equivalent. That's because `ArrayList` is not covariant as a generic type. Or in other words, `ArrayList<T>` is not a pure producer of `T`; specifically, the `ArrayList` method `add(T)` **consumes** a `T`.

But there are generic types that are pure producers, like `Iterator` or `Iterable`. Whatever you can do with an `Iterator<Integer>` you can also do with an `Iterator<? extends Integer>`. There is no method like `ArrayList.add(T)` in `Iterator<T>`.

I just want to make sure that my interface `Source<T>` is like `Iterator<T>` rather than like `ArrayList<T>`. If someone in the future adds a `T`-consuming method (like `add(T)`) to my interface, I want them to get an explicit error.

**A more complex example**

Simply banning parameters of type `T` from appearing in the interface is not a full solution. One should also note that `T` might be used as argument to other generic types. For example, the following method should not be allowed in `Source<T>`:

```
public void copyTo(List<T> destination);
```

because an sneaky subclass may try to read from the list, it is considered a `T`-consumer; you cannot call this method on a `Source<? extends Foo>`. On the other hand, this one should be allowed:

```
public void copyTo(List<? super T> destination);
```

(There is also another rule that says methods in `Source<T>` cannot return a `List<T>`, but can return a `List<? extends T>`.)

Now, the actual interface can be arbitrarily complex with lots of methods, and the rules are pretty complex themselves. It is very easy to make a mistake. So I want to automate this check.

Is there a unit-testing trick, static analyzer, compiler/IDE plugin, annotation processor (for example with an `@Covariant` annotation on `T`), or any other technique or tool that can ensure this for me?

Comment: Given your link and the syntax, I assume you're talking about Java? It's worth being explicit in the tags.

Comment: How about using something like `FooSource<F extends Foo> extends Source<F>`?

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but too long to fit in a comment.

> So it is a reasonable expectation that whatever you can do with a `Source<Foo>`, should be also possible to do if you have a `Source<? extends Foo>`

No, it is not a reasonable expectation. You linked to an entire pdf and it goes to a [top level page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.html) so it is unclear how you determined this is reasonable, but in general you cannot arbitrarily replace a `Foo<T>` with a `Foo<? extends T>`. Foe example, if you have an `ArrayList<Integer> a` you can call `a.Add(Interger.valueOf(5))` but you cannot do that if `a` is  `ArrayList<? extends Integer> a`.

It is also unclear what are `Consumer<T>` and `sendTo`. Is the latter a method in `Source<T>`>?

Without these clarifications, I am afraid he question is ambiguous.

Comment: You were wight, it was quite ambiguous. I hope it is better now.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you don't want to have any put() method in your interface, all you have to do is not to write any and leave a comment to that effect somewhere in the code; preferably with a lot of asterixes around it.

Honestly, I don't understand at all the usefulness of having a feature that would give a language the possibility of blocking some contravariant methods to a class or an interface.  This is the responsability of the programer, not the compilator.

It's the same thing as if you would ask for a feature that would give you the possibility of blocking the addition of any function that would accept an Integer as one of its parameter or as its return value.  Having such a feature in a language would be totally useless in my opinion.

Comment: I don't think it's valid criticism. The same could be said about virtually any form of static analysis.

Comment: Well, the contract for an interface is about its methods: you define the abstract methods a(), b(), c()... and you ask anyone extending this interface into a class to implements these abstract methods.  What you are asking for is the way to block the addition to this interface of any methods that would follow some particular (and totally arbitrary) signature.  Honestly, what's the point?  For the rest, if you want to insist, you should write a clear example about what you mean exactly with your "reasonable expectation about Source<Foo> and Source<? extends Foo>". Personally, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer you are looking for, but I guess you could enforce it in your interface declaration.

### Enfoce Contravariant Use

```
public interface Consumer<T, S extends T> {
   public void consume(S item);
}

public static class ConsumerImpl<T, S extends T> implements Consumer<T, S> {

   private List<? super S> items = new ArrayList<T>();

   public void consume(S item) {
      this.items.add(item);
   }

}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
Consumer<Object, String> consumer = new ConsumerImpl<Object, String>();
consumer.consume("Whatever");
consumer.consume("Another");
```

### Enforce Covariant Use

The contrary, of course, is also possible:

```
public interface Producer<T, S extends T> {
   public T produce();
}

public static class ProducerImpl<T, S extends T> implements Producer<T,S> {

   private Deque<? extends T> items = new ArrayDeque<S>();

   public ProducerImpl(Deque<S> items) {
      this.items = items;
   }

   public T produce() {
      return items.pop();
   }

}
```

And you could use it like this:

```
Deque<Integer> myInts = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
myInts.push(1);
myInts.push(2);

Producer<Number, Integer> producer = new ProducerImpl<Number, Integer>(myInts);
Number n1 = producer.produce();
Number n2 = producer.produce();
```

In both cases I have enforced that the underlying structure is either contravariant or covariant.

Comment: But you can also have `interface Confused<T, S extends T> {
    public void consume(S item);
    public T produce();
}`. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: @Saintali Of course you can! The problem with Java generics is that they are based on the concept of use-site declarions and not as it is in C# or Scala where it is based on declaration-site annotations.